# How to read portions of a big gz file with PHP

Tags: php, gzip

I need to read a big txt file (more than 1GB) in order to extract multiple strings inside it. Using gzread, I'm able to read from the beginning to an amount of kb (let's say 1000000). But how can I read the next 1000000kb of the file?
Is there a way to start from a point and read 1000000kb from there until the file is not finished?

```
$filename = "my_big_file.txt.gz";
$zd = gzopen($filename, "r");
$readfile = gzread($zd,1000000); 
$first_array = explode("IT\\",$readfile);
unset($first_array[0]);
foreach($first_array as $row){
  $full_id = explode(" ",$full_id);
  echo $full_id[0];
  echo "<br>";
}
gzclose($zd);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update; to get a specific part without a while loop

```php
$filename = "my_big_file.txt.gz";
$zd = gzopen($filename, "r");
fseek($zd, 1000000); # jump to a new position here 
$readfile = gzread($zd,1000000);
//...process $readfile 
gzclose($zd);
```

## Example

### A text file (test.txt)

Given is the following text file:

```
12345678
```

### Gzip it

Gzip the text file with:

```
gzip test.txt
```

A new file is created: `test.txt.gz`

### Demo

```php
function getGzFileChunk(string $filename, int $start, int $end) 
{
    $zd = gzopen($filename, "r");
    fseek($zd, $start);
    $readfile = gzread($zd, $end);
    gzclose($zd);
    return $readfile;
}

var_dump(getGzFileChunk("test.txt.gz", 3, 2)); //output: 45
var_dump(getGzFileChunk("test.txt.gz", 1, 2)); //output: 23
var_dump(getGzFileChunk("test.txt.gz", 4, 2)); //output: 56
var_dump(getGzFileChunk("test.txt.gz", 6, 2)); //output: 78
var_dump(getGzFileChunk("test.txt.gz", 2, 2)); //output: 34
```

## Old answer

Place the `gzread` in a while loop, like so:

```php
<?php

$filename = "my_big_file.txt.gz";
$zd = gzopen($filename, "r");
while($readfile = gzread($zd,1000000)) {
    //...your process
}
gzclose($zd);
```

Comment: It works at the begging but after some seconds I get a 500 error

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: you do `$first_array = explode("IT\\",$readfile);`, but who says that the next chunk of data contains `"IT\\"`?

Comment: the page crash. Actually is chrome that says Code error: 5

Comment: how large is the file exactly? And more important how large is the output? Because if you parse a body large enough, I suppose chrome can crash. Is it not better to write the output to a file instead of showing it in a browser?

Comment: 245MB gzipped and 1.04GB unzipped. Whitout printing anything, but saving the output in a mysql db, after 4 minutes I get a 504 Gateway Timeout error...

Answer (score 2):

If you mean: can you start reading the second million bytes of a gzip file without having read the first million bytes, then the answer is no. You cannot randomly access a gzip file.

Comment: What other way would you suggest?

Comment: All you can do is read and decompress from the beginning, until you get to the part you want.

Comment: Not true, you can use `fseek($zd, $newPositionHere);`. See my updated answer

Comment: @Douma And guess what that does? Try it on a really big gzip file.

Comment: is this a trick question? It just moves the file pointer. "All you can do is read and decompress from the beginning, until you get to the part you want."  is simply not true...

Comment: I tried fseek on a large file (10GB) and a small file (1MB). And the execution time was for the large file: `0.00012707710266113` and for the small file `0.00011777877807617`.

Comment: Yes, of course you have to read. Otherwise there was no point in seeking. Try seeking to the middle of the large gzip file and reading two bytes.